# Safely Send and Receive Passwords in Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, security, encryption

I wrote a small tool to store data for me. 
I used input fields and an ajax request to send the data in the inputs to the database and display it afterwards.
The thing is that I want to store some passwords form login credentials of different websites and I want it to be really secure.

Now, to make it secure I was thinking of encrypting and decrypting the Password as Hash when interacting with the database.

Secondly I was thinking of implementing the Google 2 factor authentification before accessing the page where the passwords are displayed to make it more secure.

How safe is this method? I would assume, because you can decrypt the hash passswords it's not that secure but since we're using 2 facor authentification to access the page where the passswords are displayed I thought it'd make it more secure.

What would you do if you wanted it to be as secure as possible?

What are other ways to achieve this?

Would appreciate any help!
Thanks

Comment: Cryptographic hashes are irreversible by design. There's no such thing as "decrypting a hash".

Comment: If I wanted it to be as secure as possible I wouldn't build it myself. Seriously, write as little code as you possibly can. Spend some time researching off-the-shelf password managers and select one that works well. This stuff is _shockingly_ hard to get right.

Comment: Okay, thanks I'll do a bit of research